# Как сделать перегрузку метода GroupBy чтобы вывести оценки для каждого студента

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Дан класс Student:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, int age, int mark)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Mark = mark;
    }
}
```

Реализуйте метод PrintStudentsMarks, который принимает коллекцию студентов (IEnumerable) students. Метод должен для каждого студента печатать список его оценок в формате:

```
Студент {Name} с возрастом {Age}: {Оценка1}, {Оценка2}, {Оценка3}.
```

Студент отличается от другого студента, если отличается имя или возраст. Если оба параметра совпадают, значит это один и тот же студент.

Не могу понять как вывести сплошным списком оценки для студента.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, int age, int mark)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Mark = mark;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

      
        int counter = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            var b1 = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            string n = b1[0];
            int n1 = int.Parse(b1[1]);
            int n2 = int.Parse(b1[2]);
            students.Add(new Student(n, n1, n2));
        }
        var distStudent = students.GroupBy(x => x.Name, y => y.Age, new StudentIEqualityComparer());

        foreach (var student in distStudent)
        {
            var first = $"Студент {student.Name} с возрастом {student.Age}:";
            foreach (var stud in groupStudent)
            {
                first += $" {stud.Key}";
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{first}.");
        }
    }

}

}
    
public class StudentIEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Age == y.Age;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(obj.Name, obj.Age);
    }

}
```

Сделал StudentIEqualityComparer  который сравнивает имена по имени и возрасту, и не понимаю как его забросить в GroupBy, чтобы сработала перегрузка я смог отсортировать Учеников и вывести требуемый список с оценками. Подскажите что я делаю не так, как правильно реализовать решение

Пример правильного ввода и вывода:

```
7
Joseph 27 5
Vasya 20 1
Joseph 27 4
Joseph 27 5
Joseph 27 2
Vasya 20 1
Vasya 20 2
Sample Output:

Студент Joseph с возрастом 27: 5, 4, 5, 2.
Студент Vasya с возрастом 20: 1, 1, 2.
```

Comment: Добрый вечер, не получается все равно. У меня выводится имя и возраст. А мне надо чтобы под Имя и возраст все оценки вывелись. { Name = Joseph, Age = 27 } пытаюсь вывести через Key но там вот ак раз имя и возраст

Comment: Если в эту перегрузку добавляю x.Mark то опять же не получаю все оценки и не понимаю как мне их вывести одной строкой получается такое что-то { Name = Joseph, Age = 27, Mark = 5 }
{ Name = Vasya, Age = 20, Mark = 1 }
{ Name = Joseph, Age = 27, Mark = 4 }
{ Name = Joseph, Age = 27, Mark = 2 }
{ Name = Vasya, Age = 20, Mark = 2 }

Comment: Еще пропадает одна оценка почему-то Joseph 27 5 должно быть 2,а у меня остается 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var grouped = students.GroupBy(
    x => x,
    x => x.Mark,
    new StudentIEqualityComparer()
);

foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    var result = $"Студент {group.Key.Name} с возрастом {group.Key.Age}:";

    foreach (var mark in group)
    {
        result += $" {mark}";
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{result}.");
}
```

Так как компаратор принимает `Student`, то и первое выражение - keySelector - в методе `GroupBy` должно выдавать объект этого типа. Отсюда `x => x` - оставляем студента без изменений.

Второе выражение - elementSelector - принимает студента и выдаёт его оценку: `x => x.Mark`.

---

Ключом группы - group.Key - является `Student`. Поэтому просто используем его свойства.

В саму группу помещены оценки. Т. е. `mark` в цикле `foreach` имеет тип `int`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, теперь понял!